# Can't achieve dependency injection oustide a controller in Spring Booot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am new at spring MVC framework and i am currently working in a web application that uses a session scoped bean to control some data flow.
I can access these beans in my application context using *@Autowired* annotation without any problem in the controllers. The problem comes when I use a class in service layer that does not have any request mapping (*@RequestMapping*, *@GetMapping* nor *@PostMapping*) annotation.
When I try to access the application context directly or using *@Autowired* or even the *@Resource* annotation the bean has a *null* value.

I have a configuration class as follow:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@EnableJpaRepositories(repositoryFactoryBeanClass = EnversRevisionRepositoryFactoryBean.class, basePackages = "com.quantumx.nitididea.NITIDideaweb.repository")
public class AppConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    
    @Bean (name = "lastTemplate")
    @SessionScope
    public LastTemplate getlastTemplate() {
        return new LastTemplate();
    }
//Some extra code

}
```

The POJO class is defined as :

```
public class LastTemplate {
    
    private Integer lastId;
    
    public LastTemplate(){
        
    }

    public Integer getLastId() {
        return lastId;
    }

    public void setLastId(Integer lastId) {
        this.lastId = lastId;
    }

}
```

The I have a Test class that is annotated as service and does not have any request mapping annotated method:

```
//@Controller
@Service
public class Test {
    
//   @Autowired
//   private ApplicationContext context;    
    
//  @Autowired
    @Resource(name = "lastTemplate")
    public LastTemplate lastTemplate;
    
//  @Autowired
//  public void setLastTemplate(LastTemplate lastTemplate) {
//      this.lastTemplate = lastTemplate;
//  }

    public Test() {
    }
    
//  @RequestMapping("/test")
    public String testing() {
//      TemplateForma last = (TemplateForma) context.getBean("lastInsertedTemplate");
//      System.out.println(last);
        System.out.println(lastTemplate);
//      System.out.println(context.containsBean("lastTemplate"));
//      System.out.println(context.getBean("lastTemplate"));
        System.out.println("Testing complete");
        return "Exit from testing method";
//      return "/Messages/Success";
    }
}
```

As you can see, there is a lot of commented code to show all the ways i have been trying to access my application context, using an Application context dependency, autowiring, declaring a resource and trying with a request mapping. The bean is null if no controller annotation and request mapping method is used and throws a java null pointer exception when I use the context getBean() methods.

Finally I just test my class in a controller that i have in my app:

```
@RequestMapping("/all")
    public String showAll(Model model) {
        
        Test test = new Test();
        test.testing();

        return "/Administrator/test";
    }
```

Worth to mention that I also tried to change the scope of the bean to a Application scope and singleton, but it not worked. How can access my application context in a service class without mapping a request via controller?

Comment: You cannot access session scoped beans from application scoped beans.

Comment: Regardless of mechanism, you generally _shouldn't_ do this; in nearly all cases it's better to isolate a concept such as a "session" to the Web tier (controllers) and pass any necessary per-request objects as parameters.

Comment: Session scope for controllers would not be the way I'd go.  You want your controllers and services to be idempotent - stateless.  Your controller should be injected with services.   You're new to Spring.  It's important to get this right.  The code you've posted is confusing to me.  I'd recommend leaving the Test out of it for now.  Mocks are a better way to go for unit testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What worked for me is that session scoped bean had to be removed in the application configuration declaration and moved to the POJO definition as follows:

```
@Component
@SessionScope    
public class LastTemplate {
    
    private Integer lastId;
    
    public LastTemplate(){
        
    }

    public Integer getLastId() {
        return lastId;
    }

    public void setLastId(Integer lastId) {
        this.lastId = lastId;
    } 
}
```

The I just call the bean using *@Autowired* annotation.

Answer (score 0):

> Worth to mention that I also tried to change the scope of the bean to a Application scope and singleton, but it not worked

It should have worked in this case.

> How can access my application context in a service class without mapping a request via controller?

Try one of these :-

`@Autowired private ApplicationContext appContext;`

OR

Implement `ApplicationContextAware` interface in the class where you want to access it.

**Edit:**

If you still want to access `ApplicationContext` from non spring managed class. Here is the link to article which shows how it can be achieved.

[This page gives an example to get spring application context object with in non spring managed classes as well](http://www.java2novice.com/spring/application-context-object/)